# Comment « trancher » glisse-t-il sémantiquement pour signifier « décider » ?

Tags: étymologie

Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « couper en tranches, taillader » avec « statuer » ?

[TRANCHER : Définition de TRANCHER](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trancher)

> [A][2.]**c)** Mettre fin à une difficulté en faisant un choix, en prenant une décision; résoudre une affaire, une question de manière définitive. Synon. *résoudre*.

> [B][3.]b) Qqn/qqc. tranche. Décider, résoudre d'une manière nette, franche, catégorique.

Comment: Cela vient du *nœud Gordien* https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C5%93ud_gordien & https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/trancher-le-noeud-gordien

Comment: Cela semble pertinent, n'hésite pas à en faire une réponse, si concise soit-elle, plutôt qu'un commentaire pour que l'on puisse avoir une réponse acceptée à cette question et éviter de laisser des questions en suspens. :)

Comment: Locuteur natif, je ne suis pas d'accord avec le sens donné par wiktionnaire. Trancher n'est pas synonyme de décider, mais plutôt de "l'action de choix définitif parmi plusieurs options faisant débat". Ce qui revient à *séparer*(trancher) les différentes options pour n'en garder qu'une au détriment des autres

Answer (score 2):

L'origine semble venir d'une autre expression figurée: *le nœud du problème*.

> Fig. Difficulté principale, point essentiel d’une affaire, d’une question. Voilà le nœud du problème, du débat. Trancher le nœud de la question, de la difficulté.

<sup>*Source: https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9N0524*</sup>

En ce sens, vu que *couper* et *trancher* sont des synonymes, il devient évident que le plus simple pour résoudre un problème, en s'attaquant, donc, au nœud du problème est de le couper, ou le trancher, et non d'essayer de le démêler.

> Trancher s’emploie aussi figurément. Trancher la difficulté, le nœud de la difficulté, Résoudre tout d’un coup une question difficile ; lever tout d’un coup un obstacle, une difficulté.

<sup>*Source: https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8T0998*</sup>

*Trancher le nœud du problème* est donc un synonyme de *décider de la solution à utiliser pour résoudre un problème*, et, à force de sous-entendus, trancher, serait donc devenu un synonyme figuré de décider.

Je ne suis donc pas certain, ici, que le *nœud gordien* soit l'expression qui soit apparue en premier, ou si c'est une de ces expressions métaphoriques basées sur la mythologie romaine comme *riche comme Crésus* ou *se croire sorti de la cuisse de Jupiter* dont le français est friand, vu ses racines latines.